# recursive method of multipliction hellp please

Tags: java

could anyone help me in this project

Write a recursive method that multiplies all values from k up to n and returns the result(as a double). For example: if k= 5, and n= 10, then multiply 5 * 6 * 7 * 8* 9 * 10 to return 151200.

in java code

```
public static int multiply(int k, int n) {
if(k == n) {
    return k;
}
return k * multiply(k, n-1);
}
```

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: Have you already tryed something?Try something and come back to seek help if you run into problems.People dont do homeworks here.

Comment: yes i try some method but its not run with me

Comment: this is wha i write it

Comment: int multiply(int x, int y) {
    if(y == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return x + multiply(x, y - 1);
}

Comment: use * instead of + ? ;)

Comment: i change it bu i give me wrong result

Comment: The original question has been improved.  I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

The first part in doing anything recursize is defining a base case.  In this case, your base case is when `k` is equal to `n`, in which case, the method should return `k`.

Next, something to handle a situation in which the given inputs won't work (for example, if `k` starts as a number larger than `n`).  Perhaps return 0 or something?

Once you've got these two things in place, do the recursive part.  `k` should grow toward `n`.

---

After your edit, you're quite close.

You just need to change your return statement.  As I said, `k` needs to grow toward `n`, but you're shrinking `n` toward `k`.  Do this instead:

```
return k * multiply(k+1, n);
```

As you currently have it written, you're returning `k * k * k ...` until `n` has been decreased to equal `k`.  Which is effectively just `k` to the `nth` power.

Using this return will give you `k * k + 1 * k + 2 * k + 3 ...` until `k` has been increased to equal `n`.

Comment: i try and it give me 15625 as a result it wrong here should be 151200

Comment: Edit your original post to show the code you're using (and if you do that, I'll vote to reopen) (and add details to the answer).  EDIT: You're getting that answer because you're shrinking `n` instead of growing `k`.